# How to point to a formula to another cell

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I want to use a cell to type a formula and another cell to evaluate this :

```
A1 : namedRange1 * namedRange2

A2 : =ARRAYFUNCTION(namedRange1 * namedRange2)
```

But, I want to use **`A1`** as a pointer (something like *`=ARRAYFUNCTION(A1)`*) so the user enters the formula only once.

**Note** : operators (*/**-+**) are making *`INDIRECT()`* useless

Here a template of what I am trying to to:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iIv7bVM5ROT_EAYZMD6tFmsLPigad-DUrpH087-3EX0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: It isn't completely clear what you're trying to achieve. Could you create a concrete example of what the user is supposed to type where, and how you expect that to be applied?

Comment: share your sample sheet and more explain what you want?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(INDIRECT(LEFTB(A1; 11))+INDIRECT(RIGHTB(A1; 11)))
```

[image: 0]